# How to kill all buffers except the buffer current one and *other*?

Tags: buffers, kill-buffer

I use this:

```
(defun kill-other-buffers ()
    "kill all other buffers."
     (interactive)
     (mapc 'kill-buffer (delq (current-buffer) (buffer-list))))
```

I need to add one more buffer

Comment: The question isn't very clear. What other buffer? If you know what it is then just use `delq` to delete it also. Or do you mean the value of `(other-buffer (current-buffer))`? If so, use `del` on its return value. See `C-h f other-buffer`.

Comment: If you want to exclude a buffer with a known name then you'll probably be looking for `(get-buffer BUFFER-OR-NAME)` to obtain the value to be deleted from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, you can simply `delq` the "one more buffer" you wish to exclude.  You would be deleting it from the list which was returned by the initial `delq` form:

```el
(delq (get-buffer "init.el")
      (delq (current-buffer)
            (buffer-list)))
```

You can, of course, generalise this to act on some arbitrary list of exclusions:

```el
(require 'cl-lib)
(let ((exclusions (list (current-buffer) (get-buffer "init.el"))))
  (cl-reduce #'delq exclusions :from-end t :initial-value (buffer-list)))
```

Or you might find this approach more-readable:

```el
(require 'cl-lib)
(let ((exclusions (list (current-buffer) (get-buffer "init.el"))))
  (cl-loop for b being the buffers
           unless (memq b exclusions)
           collect b))
```

All three forms should return the same list.

Comment: Thanks! Is just what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (depending on your needs) is to use the `kill-buffer-query-functions` hook to prevent specific buffers from being killed regardless of how `kill-buffer` is invoked.

I use my own [small library](https://github.com/glucas/buffer-protect/blob/master/buffer-protect.el) to prevent certain buffers from being killed but there are various other examples out there. With this approach you can keep your kill-other-buffers command simple and manage your list of protected buffers separately.